# Java, use array instead of SQL SELECT

Tags: java, sql, arrays, oracle, long-integer

I have one script which fetches around 25.000 different ID values and uses them to make some changes in other table. But the programmer created this code which searches ID (dialid in the code) through the table of 10 million records (line 3) and every query in loop is executing around 1 second. My idea is to fetch last 30 days of records with the SQL and to put it into an array and check only the array.

And my question is, how to do that in Java? Is it the in_array function? I'm solid in PHP, but beginner in Java code...

---

```
private Integer getDialId(int predictiveId) {
 Integer dialid = null;
 StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT dialid from dial where PREDICTIVE_DIALID=");
    sql.append(predictiveId); //this predictiveId is calculated in other part of code
    ResultSet rsDialId = null;

    Statement s1 = null;
    try {

        s1 = oracle.getConn().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT);

        rsDialId = s1.executeQuery(String.valueOf(sql));
        if (rsDialId.next()) {
            dialid = rsDialId.getInt("dialid");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MediatelCdrSync.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (s1 != null) {
                s1.close();
            }
            if (rsDialId != null) {
                rsDialId.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MediatelCdrSync.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("DIALID = " + dialid);
    return dialid;
}
```

Thnx

Comment: Consider creating an SQL query or a PL/SQL procedure that _make some changes in other tables_,  and then run this code on the database server side - in this way you will awoid fetching 25.000 records to the client over the network and sending them back to another tables.

Comment: Yes, that is also a plan.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a performance problem I'd start to see why the query takes one second per execution, if it's database time because the dial table does not have and index on PREDICTIVE_DIALID column you can do very little at the java level.
Anyway the jdbc code reveals some problems especially when used with an oracle database.
The biggest issue is that you are hardcoding your query parameter causing Oracle to re"hard parse" the query every time; the second (minor one) is that the resultset is scrollable and updatable while you need only to load the first row. If you want to make some little modification to your code you should change to somethig like this pseudo code:

```
        PreparedStatement ps =connection.prepareStatement("SELECT dialid from dial where PREDICTIVE_DIALID=?");

        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {//your 25000 loop elements is this one  
            //this shoudl be the start of the body of your getDialId function that takes also a prepared statement
            ps.setInt(1, i);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                rs.getInt("dialid");    
            }
            rs.close();
            //your getDialId end here 
        }
        ps.close();
```

With this minimal java solution you should note a performance increase, but you must chek the performance of the single query since if there is a missing index you cand very little at a java code.

Another solution, more complicated, is to to create a temporart table, fill it with all the 25000 predictiveId values and then issue a query that joins dial and you temporary table; so with one resultset(and one query) you can find all the dialid you need. A jdbc batch insert into the temp table speeds up insertion time noticeably.

Comment: Thnx for the answer. I will check the indexes, but maybe I could write this problem in more simple way. 

The query 
SELECT dialid from dial where PREDICTIVE_DIALID='xyz' 
takes for 1 second to execute because it searches through 10 million records (aprox 5 years of data). Maybe I could narrow the search to fetch last 200.000 records (last 30 days) in some array and to check within this array?

Comment: @t-rex_vg I think that filtering records in java is slower that on the db. If you want to load the last records and check inside them I suggest to use a a Set (or a Map if you nedd an object with properties) because it's faster. 10 milllions of record is not so big for a db search if there are indexes on the field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to fetch less record and store that result in some array then
I think it is better for you to limit your search by creating a view in Database with limited record's (say record for last 2 year's)
And Use that view in your select query

```
"SELECT dialid from dial_view WHERE PREDICTIVE_DIALID = "
```

Hope it will help :)